# Reading, Creating, and Manipulating full Frame in TCP/IP network communication via C++ coded client and server

Tags: c++, server, tcp, client

I would like to code my own client and server in C++ (which I have found plenty of tutorials on) and access to all information about the headers and all the fields in a frame that is going to be sent across a network.

I need it to be able to edit and/or manipulate information in all the header fields before sending the frame across the network. What's more, it needs to be able to receive a frame and read/manipulate all the header fields from layer 2 to up layer.

I just want to know what library in C++ I need to use or is there any information on how I can code something to accomplish this via C++ that I can be directed to?

Comment: You'd need to be part of the OS kernel to do that deep inspection of the network stack. On Linux, write a kernel module or a [EBPF](http://www.brendangregg.com/ebpf.html) program for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct a client/server, it's easy. But if you want to build a packet from MAC to Transport Layer, then you need to use the Linux kernel. You need to have some knowledge about how the packets are sent and received. What's more, we always use C to realise it.